# Cannot bind ko.observable array to foreach loop

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, ko.observablearray

I have a simple viewModel that I am creating from a MVC for to json string, I am using ko.mapping to accomplish this.

```
var initialTicketData = {"Ticket": [{"ID":1,"EventID":506596,"Name":"General Admission","Quantity":100,"Price":15.0},{"ID":2,"EventID":506596,"Name":"Backstage Passes","Quantity":25,"Price":50.0}]};

var ticketViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(initialTicketData);

ko.applyBindings(ticketViewModel);
```

I want to iterate through this array and display the data on the page. I am trying to use a foreach data-binding.

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: ticketViewModel.Ticket">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: ticketViewModel.Name"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: ticketViewModel.Price"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: ticketViewModel.Quantity"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

However, when I try to run I get the following error.

> "Unable to parse bindings. Message: ReferenceError: ticketViewModel is not defined; Bindings value: foreach: ticketViewModel.Ticket"

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: Ticket">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Price"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Quantity"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Bindings are always relative to the current context.  When you say `ko.applyBindings(ticketViewModel);` you set the "root" context to `ticketViewModel`. Then when you use a 'foreach' you add a new context, and bindings inside the 'foreach' are now relative to each Ticket element.

Comment: I tried that and still failed. A bit of information I failed to mention is that there are two models attached to this page. The other model "eventViewModel" has only ko.observables, is also loaded via the mapping plugin, and I use the "eventViewModel.Name" to bind to the event name. All works well with this model.

Comment: If you have more than one ViewModel on a page you should either:

1) Create a large ViewModel that contains two sub models and do `ko.applyBindings(viewModel);` and then use a `with: ticketViewModel` binding to scope an area to the sub model.

2) Use the form `ko.applyBindings(ticketViewModel, document.getElementById('someElementId'));` to set the root view model for a particular section of the DOM.

Comment: I am confused... Either: ... ? Is it poor practice to have multiple view models per page?

Comment: Ahhh... I jumped the gun . I will try this. Thank you!

Comment: John, thank you for your help. You were correct. To resolve my issue I compiled the smaller views into a single all-encompassing viewModel. Works like a champ.